# Selecting a select option using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAKFv/2/) to see my problem.

I am selecting a time from `td` and want to select an option from drop down based on that.

It's working fine in IE8 and down. But not working in Chrome and IE9.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="time">
            11:20:12
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<select id="StartHour" name="DateRangeFromSeconds">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="37">37</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="39">39</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="41">41</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="43">43</option>
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="47">47</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="49">49</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="51">51</option>
    <option value="52">52</option>
    <option value="53">53</option>
    <option value="54">54</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="56">56</option>
    <option value="57">57</option>
    <option value="58">58</option>
    <option value="59">59</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
var s=$('#time').html().split(':');
alert(s[0]); // I'm getting the value here. How can I set this value in the drop down list?
$("#StartHour option[value='" +s[0] + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the table cell's content you're getting all the leading and trailing whitespace as well as the text that you're interested in; also, you should use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `.html()` just in case. So, just strip out the whitespace using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var s = $('#time').text().replace(/\s/g, '').split(':');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xmgAu/

Comment: `text()` didnt worked .But the given solution worked .Thank you

Comment: @Null: The given solution uses `text()` *and* `replace`.

Comment: ok :) sorry ..I thought will get answer only using `text()` without using `replace` .Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to set the value of a drop down select element:

```
var s=$('#time').html().split(':');
alert(s[0]); // here i am getting value .. How can i set this value in drop down list
$("#StartHour").val(s[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

using .html or .text is not the matter. The matter is you should remove white spaces and set the value using $("#id").val(index).So your corrected code is as follows:

```
var s = $('#time').html().replace(/\s/g, '').split(':');//white space removed
alert(s[0]); // here i am getting value
$("#StartHour").val(s[0]); //Here i am setting this value in drop down list
```

This should work.I had already tested this at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/tAKFv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#StartHour option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");

$("#StartHour option[value="+s[0]+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#StartHour").val(s[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#StartHour").val(parseInt(s[0]));
```

instead of

```
$("#StartHour option[value='" +s[0] + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```